# How to remove product features for a specific category in Magento?

Tags: product

I'd like to remove the product tabs, add to links and related products for a specific category in Magento

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Go to your category and in "Custom Design" tab then set "Apply to products" to "Yes" and add following code in "Custom Layout Update"

```
    <reference name="product.info.tabs">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>additional</child>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

Here `additional` is the tab name difined in catalog.xml that I am removing.